# how do I remove Div after click

Tags: jquery, html

Is it possible for the div tag to be removed after one
 of the three buttons are clicked so a game can start?

```
   $(game).ready(function(){

    $('#game').append('<div id="dialog"><h5>Difficulty</h5>'
        +'<button id="Btn">Easy</button>'
        +'<button id="Btn">Medium</button>'
        +'<button id="Btn">Hard</button></div>');

        $("dialog").onclick().remove();



});
```

Comment: Thanks, but the dialog doesnt open on the web page when it, any ideas?

Comment: What? You're missing the hash-symbol in the id for `$('#dialog')`

Comment: `$(game).ready(function(){`. What is `game`? :)

Comment: suppose to be document -.- lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
$("dialog").onclick().remove();
```

with

```
$("#dialog").click(function(){$(this).remove();});
```

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dnsxp084/)